# Navbar toggler (bootstrap 4) is working but invisible. I can't see it but can be clicked and it is working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

> quote       This is my simple code and I have no idea why it is not working? The toggle button is not visible and whatever background color my navbar is, it overlaps the button without a button is visible. I am trying to learn this technology and I am a total beginner so please don't mind if I am doing a very silly mistake

```
<body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-lt navbar-expand-sm fixed-top nb">
            <div class = "container">
                <button class = "navbar-toggler" type = "button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target = "#Navbar">
                    <i class="navbar-toggler-icon"></i>
                </button>

                <a class = " mr-auto navbar-brand myfont" href = ".\index.html">Sidhant Aggarwal</a>
                <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse" id = "Navbar">
                <ul class = "navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class = "nav-item"> <a class = "nav-link" href= "#"> About Me</a></li>
                <li class = "nav-item"> <a class = "nav-link" href= "#"> Resume</a></li>
                <li class = "nav-item"> <a class = "nav-link" href= ".\contactus.html">Certifications</a></li>
                </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

  This is the CSS stylesheet
    .nb{

        height: 100px;
        letter-spacing: 0.2em;
        line-height: 70px;
        letter-spacing: 0.2em;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        text-align: left;
        margin: 0px auto;
        color:black;


    }

    .navbar-brand{

        padding-right: 20px;
        color:black;
        margin-left: 80px;
        padding-right: 20px;


    }

    .nav-item{
        color: black;
        font-family: "Lato";

    }




    Please help!


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMZPu.png
```

Comment: Seems like jquery v3.5.0 and bootstrap v4.4.1 is having some issues. Just make sure you are using different versions and check

Comment: I just made sure jquery 3.4.1 is working for me

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "bootstrap-social": "^5.1.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.12.9"
  }

Comment: I even tried with bootstrap 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in your code... `navbar-lt` seems to be wrong

- change `<nav class="navbar navbar-lt navbar-expand-sm fixed-top nb">`
- into `<nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-sm fixed-top nb">`

and you'll be on your way...

```css
.nb {
  height: 100px;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  line-height: 70px;
  letter-spacing: 0.2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 0px auto;
  color: black;
}

.navbar-brand {
  padding-right: 20px;
  color: black;
  margin-left: 80px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}

.nav-item {
  color: black;
  font-family: "Lato";
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-sm fixed-top nb">
  <div class="container">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Navbar">
                    <i class="navbar-toggler-icon"></i>
                </button>

    <a class=" mr-auto navbar-brand myfont" href=".\index.html">Sidhant Aggarwal</a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="Navbar">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#"> About Me</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href="#"> Resume</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"> <a class="nav-link" href=".\contactus.html">Certifications</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```